# How to verticaly merge in a single cell all the rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string

Given a pandas dataframe:

```
l1 = ["Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?",
     "Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.",
     "Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.",
     "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who",
     "he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."]


l2 = ["Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.",
     "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.",
     "Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est.",
     "Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.",
     "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?"]


a = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=['Col 1'])
b = pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=['Col 2'])

df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
```

How can I concat in a single cell, vertically the all rows belowe the column. That is, the dataframe shape should go from `(5, 2)` to `(2, 2)`, where the frist row are the names of the columns and the second row is the concatnation of all the strings, separated by a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1).apply(' '.join).to_frame().T
```

Or safer (when `a` and `b` don't have the same size):

```
pd.concat([x.apply('\n'.join) for x in (a,b)]).to_frame().T
```

Output (note that this has shape 1 x 2):

```
                                               Col 1                                              Col 2
0  Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercit...  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus erro...
```

Comment: Thanks, not really,  The shape is `(2,)`, the shape should be `(2, 2)` it should be to the other side, vertically, not horizontally. I tried to transpose it but still is wrong

Comment: @anon see updated answer. However, I don't think it's the best way to format your data. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why you dont think it is the best way to go? Also it is still wrong, the columns should remain the same, should I use axis as 0?

Comment: I don't understand, how can you have two rows if the column names are the same while concatenating all strings?

Comment: yes, the original col names should remain as col names, not as index

Comment: Updated the answer. If it's not what you mean, then you should specify the expected output .

Answer (score 1):

first this is NOT the right way to use pandas :D
second, I tried to hack my way, here is a step by step

join text togeter

```
df['Col 1'] =  df.groupby(level=0)['Col 1'].transform(lambda x : '\n'.join(x)).sum()
df['Col 2'] =  df.groupby(level=0)['Col 2'].transform(lambda x : '\n'.join(x)).sum()
```

This has each row with all the text, so we select only one row

```
df = df.iloc[0,[0,1]]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df).transpose()
```

which gives you this

```
    Col 1                                               Col 2  
0   Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercit...   Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus erro...
```

what is left is adding the column as a row at the end

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = df.columns.values.tolist()
```

and finally reverse order

```
df = df.sort_index(ascending = False)
```